# Android : Http request : get response time

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient

In ANDROID, is there any way to get the reponse time from an http request (Using httpClient for instance)

Am looking for an alternative to what [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) does.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no API to get you that. General approach is to capture the time before sending the request and after reading the response. Difference between them should give you a close but not the exact time for the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i think that calculating the diference inside the android app is not much accurate.whereas with Curl, you have the exact time (+ other times) that the server took to respond